# ApplePay iOS Error on PKInAppPaymentService connection - com.apple.passd.in-app-payment - Connection to remote alert view service failed

Tags: ios, objective-c

While trying to integrate Apple Pay into my test app, I couldn't get the payment sheet to show up, even though I followed all instructions in Apple's [Getting Started with Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Getting-Started-with-Apple-Pay.pdf) document.

When making the payment request:

`PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *auth = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:paymentRequest];`

I get two weird errors, with no results on web searches:

Error on PKInAppPaymentService connection: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)" (connection to service named com.apple.passd.in-app-payment) UserInfo=0x174273780 {NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.passd.in-app-payment}

Connection to remote alert view service failed

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After following the four steps in Apple's getting started doc, the solution is hidden step number 5:

Enable Apple Pay in your project settings, on the Capabilities tab. This is arguably part of step 4 in Apple's doc, but the step that really tripped me up was checking on the merchant id as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Enable Apple Pay - Screenshot]

Edit: Also see answer from @ChristopherJones if you still have trouble.

(Make sure the merchantId you use with a payment request is exactly the same as the one in your Apple Pay capabilities section. Remove the alphanumeric stuff in the beginning if you included it.)

After that, just build and run again.

Comment: I spent an hour or two only to realize there was even a checkbox I was supposed to check there.  I had otherwise enabled+renabled that about 5 times by now...  Thanks!

Comment: i have been facing the same problem from past one week. i followed the same steps. i enabling the apple pay in ios and check the merchant id and first step only is in correct symbol ,remaining two steps show the error like cross symbol. due to that one i encountered that issue? .

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue and the problem was you have to make sure your PKPaymentRequest's merchantIdentifier matches exactly without the random number. Also, you need to make sure that the same identifier is check marked in the Capabilities tab.

```
PKPaymentRequest *request = [PKPaymentRequest new];
request.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.com.example";
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I didn't understand your solution. could please explain more details

Answer (score 2):

Also can happen if you subclass from `PKPaymentRequest` and feed your subclass to `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`

Comment: Is there documentation that explains that we cannot subclass PKPaymentRequest. I just lost a good chunk amount of time... so thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it for "All"

I had "Connection to remote alert view service failed" error too. For me it turned out that I added Apple Pay in Cababilities Tab, but only for Debug. Once I added it for "All" it started working